# Centering a picture

Tags: support, formatting

Is it possible to center a picture added in a question on the SE sites? I can not find any centering option on the help pages.

Answer (score 3):

[This was answered on Meta.StackExchange a number of years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/is-it-possible-to-horizontally-center-an-image-on-stack-exchange-sites). There are two answers

## **Method 1**:

Using `<pre></pre>` tags to manually position the HTML image call (in this case, `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9ETl.png alt="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9ETl.png" title="CENTERED!">`). As an example, look here:

Note that I had to *manually* add the 22 spaces to center that (it looks centered on my monitor at least!).

## **Method 2:**

Using many `&nbsp;`'s in front of the image (in this case `![alt text][1]` where `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9ETl.png`)

[image: this is my profile image]

There are 35 of those `&nbsp;` in that line to center it.