# How can I edit my own questions and answers?

Tags: support, editing, mathjax

How can I edit my own questions and answers for example, give the symbols for pi, integration, and draw diagrams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [the Notation page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation). It provides a mini-tutorial on the use of inline equations and centered equations. For pi, you want \pi and for integrals, you want \int (I'd wrap those with $ to start MathJax, but it is not enabled on Meta).

Sadly, there is no method to draw figures via [tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) or [\includegraphics](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics) in the normal Latex methods. However, there is a [button to include the graphics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) (circled below):

[image]

which can be used to pull an image from a website or from your computer. Also sadly, [there is *not* an easy way to center the image](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6446/centering-a-picture/6447#6447).

Comment: For diagrams I find Google Draw to be good enough for most things. I draw the diagram in Google Draw then screen grab it and paste into Paint Shop Pro (other image editing apps are available). For graphs I use Excel, but Google Sheets is pretty good and free.